# Set default server in powershell for AD related commands

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Recently my powershell scripts require to explicitly say which domain I want to connect to. Is it necessary to write this for each command? Or can I set it somehow once in the beginning of the script.

Instead of
Get-ADUser -Server server otherparameters

could I write in the beginning something like
Set-default server to connect to
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to write this for each command?

### No!

You can specify a default parameter value for a parameter belonging to one or more cmdlets by assigning it to the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` automatic variable:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*-AD*:Server'] = 'mydc.mydomain.tld'
```

Any cmdlet you subsequently invoke that matches the `*-AD*` pattern by name and has a `-Server` parameter will now implicitly have `'mydc.mydomain.tld'` bound to the `-Server` parameter unless an argument is explicitly passed.

In other words: next time you invoke `Get-ADUser rsterba`, PowerShell now calls `Get-ADUser rsterba -Server 'mydc.mydomain.tld'` instead.

For more information about `$PSDefaultParameterValues` and how it works, see the [`about_Parameters_Default_Values` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.2)

---

If you want to pass the same argument but *selectively*, use partial [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to avoid re-typing `-Server ...`:

```
# define target DC in a hashtable
$srv = @{ Server = 'mydc.mydomain.tld'}
# ... it doesn't have to be a hardcoded value
$srv = @{ Server = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service PrimaryDC).HostName}

# `@srv` will expand to `-Server <DC hostname>`
Get-ADUser <# other parameters #> @srv

# ... but it no longer applies by default, so omitting it restore the original behavior
Get-ADUser <# other parameters #>
```